# EDF 2025 - Max number of crates on field?

Tags: earth-defense-force, earth-defense-force-2025

In Earth Defense Force 2017 there was a maximum number of crates that could be on the field at any one time (to guard against the machine running out of resources). I am wondering what is the maximum number of crates that can be on the field at any one time in EDF 2025, since they are not sprites in this version but proper 3D objects with physics etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be 256.

I've spent time playing on the DLC #2 pack, Mutant Rampage stage 15 with the giant wasps' nest in the city. After blasting away for a bit, the silver spiders stopped dropping items (and they are guaranteed to drop 2-3 upon death). I flew around the stage and used the radar to count and the number was 256.